# Symfony2: Best place to put business logic

Tags: symfony

I read that a good practice have entities light, only getters and setters. But I have custom methods with some logic, for example.

```
public function calculatePrice(){

  /*
 Here I have to do many math operations 
 including access to other repositories to get 
 specific data (taxes, comissions, ect) from others entities
*/


}
```

Where to put this kind "more complex methods" for do:

```
//in controller
$product->calculatePrice()  

//in twig templates
{{ product.calculatePrice }}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like to put business logic related to entities within a Service class. IMO, an entity repository should only be responsible for querying the DB for multiple items of an entity group, or very specific 'findBy' methods (ex: fetch all `Messages` belonging to `User` where `isRead = 0`).

Often times, you'll find yourself using multiple service classes to handle specific blocks of business logic - it's easier (and cleaner) to keep all of this in the service layer instead of shoe-horning it into repositories.

Using services for business logic will result in more modular code. If your `Product` entity and repo don't contain any business logic (which is usually very specific per app), you can more easily reuse those classes in other projects without having to do as much cleanup.

Comment: But using a service class i can't call $product->calculatePrice() neither in template. Inmagine you want print a simple product list whit your related price iterating over products collection. ¿Have I to call $this->get('product.service')->calculatePrice($procduct) into foreach? ¿what about print the calculated price in twig template like {{ product.calculatePrice }}?

Comment: I don't use Twig, so I apologize if I'm wrong here, but can't you 'inject' an instance of the service class and then call its method from within the loop? Is it possible to proxy to the service class through a Twig template helper?

Comment: Yes is posible extending twig and creating a function calculatePrice(). Later you can do: {{ product | calculatePrice() }}. Of course I need inject the service responsible to calculate the price into the twig extension class. Thanks.

Comment: @smoreno You could add a field (`price`) to your entity, pass the object to the service and let it set the value for the field. No need for calculating the price in the template.

Comment: I like @gilden's solution a lot. It seems cleaner to have this data added to your entities before passing them to the view layer.